# Ambiguous reference error from web service while migrating solution to VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, service-reference

i have some traditional(i guess) issue while migrating solution to VS2012 but still i couldn't find solution to resolve it!!!

i have business library project which is referenced in servicehost and the same business library is also referenced in client project which is consuming those web-services(ASMX)..we don't see any issue by referencing like that in VS2008 but now i'm trying to migrate it to VS2012 so all those ambiguous reference errors are popping up..following are the issues which i'm facing

1) when i'm trying to call webmethods from client proj those methods are expecting classes from service reference not from the referenced library though its same class.

2)so i tried to add namespaces manually to the each object TO USE NAMESPACE FROM SERVICE but i couldn't find some classes which are declared as collections in business library via service reference.

Ex:Lets say i have declared some class1 which is arraylist in business library with some properties in it..when i try to find that class from reference i couldnt.. in reference.cs its just returning an array(like class[]) but not as class1 so obviously i wont able to use the properties in it..

how can i resolve this ambiguous reference errors..when i don't see those with VS2008 why I'm seeing with VS2012..is there any way i can say don't get any classes from service reference(i guess WCF has that feature(REUSE TYPES) right!!!)

Please advice!!

Answer (score 2):

`Ambiguous reference errors`. occurs when you call two or more methods with same name from one class or more class or call two or more columns with same name from database with join query. i suggest you to check all your method names and calling sequence and queries also..
Hope you will get your answer.